# Function not returning results when executing via table data

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a homegrown batch processing engine that I use on my website. I'm trying to create a function that will get me the "NextRunDate" for all of the jobs that are enabled.

Here's the function:

```
create function dbo.uf_BatchJob_Get_NextRunDate
(
    @daysToRun varchar(19),
    @hoursToRun varchar(84)
)
returns datetime as begin
    set @daysToRun = replace(@daysToRun, ' ', '')
    set @hoursToRun = replace(@hoursToRun, ' ', '')

    declare @now datetime = getdate()
    declare @currentYear int = datepart(yyyy, @now)
    declare @currentMonth int = datepart(MM, @now)
    declare @currentDay int = datepart(dd, @now)
    declare @currentHour int = datepart(hh, @now)
    declare @timeCheck datetime = convert(varchar(4), @currentYear) + '/' + convert(varchar(2), @currentMonth) + '/' + convert(varchar(2), @currentDay) + ' ' + convert(varchar(2), @currentHour) + ':00:00.000'

    declare @foundDay bit = 0
    declare @foundHour bit = 0

    while (@foundDay = 0 or @foundHour = 0) begin
        -- increment by 1 hour
        set @timeCheck = dateadd(hh, 1, @timeCheck)

        declare @dayOfWeekCheck int = datepart(dw, @timeCheck) - 1 -- 0 based versus 1 based
        declare @hourCheck int = datepart(hh, @timeCheck)

        if (charindex(cast(@dayOfWeekCheck as varchar(1)), @daysToRun) > 0) begin
            set @foundDay = 1
        end else begin
            set @foundDay = 0
        end

        declare @hourIndex int = charindex(cast(@hourCheck as varchar(2)), @hoursToRun)
        declare @characterBefore varchar(1) = substring(@hoursToRun, @hourIndex - 1, 1)
        declare @characterAfter varchar(1) = substring(@hoursToRun, @hourIndex + len(@hourCheck), 1)

        if (@characterBefore = '') begin
            set @characterBefore = ','
        end

        if (@characterAfter = '') begin
            set @characterAfter = ''
        end

        if (@foundDay = 1) begin
            if (@hourIndex > 0 and @characterBefore = ',' and @characterAfter = ',') begin
                set @foundHour = 1
            end else begin
                set @foundHour = 0
            end
        end
    end

    -- it's been found, let's return the value
    return  @timeCheck
end
```

For info, the `@daysToRun` and `@hoursToRun` parameters are structured like this: '0, 1, 3, 6' (for days) or '2, 4, 9, 15, 19, 23' (for hours)

When I execute this function sending those example parameters explicitly, it returns exactly what I want. Like this:
select dbo.uf_BatchJob_Get_NextRunDate('0, 1, 3, 6', '2, 4, 9, 15, 19, 23')

But if I call this function in-line with live data, it never responds. Here's how I'm doing that:

```
select  x.BatchProcessId,
        x.BatchName,
        x.DaysToRun,
        x.HoursToRun,
        dbo.uf_BatchJob_Get_NextRunDate(x.DaysToRun, x.HoursToRun) [NextRunDate]
from    (
    select  bp.BatchProcessId,
            bp.BatchName,
            bps.DaysToRun,
            bps.HoursToRun
    from    dbo.BatchProcess bp
    join    dbo.BatchProcessSchedule bps on bps.BatchProcessId = bp.BatchProcessId
        and bps.[Enabled] = 1
    where   bp.[Enabled] = 1
) x
```

Why would it not respond when running it the in-line way? The subquery only returns 9 jobs that are enabled, so it's not chunking through very many records...

Edit: Oh, and I threw in the sub-select because I thought it might have been having problems trying to call the function for records that WEREN'T enabled yet, so I just wanted to make sure it was only processing the 9 jobs.

Comment: Do you get your expected result without the function call?

Comment: @MahediSabuj "without the function call" do you mean just calling it directly, like this `select dbo.uf_BatchJob_Get_NextRunDate('0, 2', '1, 3')`. If so, yes

Comment: Nope, try to remove this part form the select query, `dbo.uf_BatchJob_Get_NextRunDate(x.DaysToRun, x.HoursToRun) [NextRunDate]`and check you get expected result or not?

Comment: @MahediSabuj oh yes, that runs just fine and returns the 9 jobs.

Comment: **can you show your sub-query result?** And looks like your live data never make this condition `while(@foundDay = 0 or @foundHour = 0)` falsy. you can try one by one from the result like `select dbo.uf_BatchJob_Get_NextRunDate(yourDaysToRunValue, yourHoursToRun)`

Comment: @MahediSabuj `@foundDay` and `@foundHour` work fine because I confirmed that calling it directly without the table data. I can even copy values from an actual batch job and it works fine. It DOESN'T work when I actually pull the values from the table via a select statement. I'll attach the results of the subquery in the question...

Comment: what datatypes are DaysToRun and HoursToRun

Comment: @JamieD77 they are strings. Examples are above in the question.

Comment: examples of your parameters are in the question but there's no mention of what the `BatchProcessSchedule` table structure looks like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was going on.

When the `@hoursToRun` value passed only has a single "hour", that's when the function never returns anything.

For example:

`@hoursToRun = '13' -- which would be 1:00pm`

To fix this for now, I just have to add a comma to the end and it works fine, like this:

```
set @hoursToRun = @hoursToRun + ','
```